# How do I run independent t-test for a list of variables in R without doing it one by one

Tags: r

For example, right now, I have to key in the t.test one at a time for each independent variables.

```
t.test(Age~composite_renal_march2020,data = DN_DKK3,var.equal=TRUE)

t.test(HbA1c~composite_renal_march2020,data = DN_DKK3,var.equal=TRUE)
```

I tried to pipe the following code to try to run t.test for the 2 variables simultaneously:

```
DN_DKK3 %>% 
  select(-SampleID) %>% 
  group_by(Age, HbA1c) %>% 
  t.test(~composite_renal_march2020, var.equal = TRUE)
```

However, the pipe code kept giving me this error message:

> Error in `vec_c()`:
> ! Can't combine `composite_renal_march2020`  and `RetinopathyGrade13` .
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

---

Backtrace:
▆

1. ├─... %>% t.test(~composite_renal_march2020, var.equal = TRUE)
2. ├─stats::t.test(., ~composite_renal_march2020, var.equal = TRUE)
3. └─stats:::t.test.default(., ~composite_renal_march2020, var.equal = TRUE)
4. ├─x[xok]
5. ├─dplyr:::`[.grouped_df`(x, xok)
6. ├─base::NextMethod()
7. └─tibble:::`[.tbl_df`(x, xok)
8. ```
   └─tibble:::tbl_subset_matrix(x, j, j_arg)
   ```
9. ```
     ├─base::unname(vec_c(!!!values, .name_spec = ~.x))
   ```
10. ```
      └─vctrs::vec_c(!!!values, .name_spec = ~.x)
    ```

Warning message:
In is.na(y) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'

I am stuck on how to solve this error message... hope to get some advice here. Thank you all so much!

Comment: Please provide some data to make the code reproducible. Please visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Surely this has been asked and answered multiple times. You are expected to do a good faith search, show what you found, tried and say why it was unsuccessful.

Comment: if you have R version 4.3 and above, you could use `SLR::multiple_tests` function. You could install the package from github ie `devtools::install_github('oonyambu/SLR')` I am not sure. You could google

Comment: `SLR::multiple_tests(.~composite_renal_march2020|Age + HbA1c, subset(data, , -SampleID)` with the default being `t.test`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question. But maybe you could do something like this:

```
data(mtcars)
# for selecting variables for testing
vars <- colnames(mtcars)[1:ncol(mtcars) - 1]

cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)
# Test everything against 'am '
res <- pbapply::pblapply(vars, function(x) t.test(mtcars[x], mtcars$am), cl = cl)
```

I am assuming that you want to test a number of variables against the same variable. This allows you to do just that and even in parallel depending on the number of corse you have you can change 2 in whatever works for you.

`res` will be a list where each entry is the output of a single [t.test()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/t.test)

I hope this helps, if not please let me know and I'll try to help.

Comment: Hi Joan! This works wonder and save so much time! Thank you so much!